# How to make form work

Tags: php, html, forms

I started a form in a PHP page and I think I have everything right were it belongs. But when I upload it to a server it doesn’t work. How to fix it?

Here is my code:

```
<section class="body">
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'From: TangledDemo';
$to = 'contact@tangledindesign.com';
$subject = 'Hello';
$human = $_POST['human'];

$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

if ($_POST['submit'] && $human == '4') {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
        echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
    } else {
        echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>';
    }
} else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
    echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
}
?>
<form method="post" action="new.php">

<label>Name</label>
<input name="name" placeholder="Type Here">

<label>Email</label>
<input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Type Here">

<label>Message</label>
<textarea name="message" placeholder="Type Here"></textarea>

<label>*What is 2+2? (Anti-spam)</label>
<input name="human" placeholder="Type Here">

<input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
</section>
```

so the error that i get is this whole line of code on my live site

```
Your message has been sent!</p>';
    } else {
        echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>';
    }
} else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
    echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Your antispam system is really funny, beware robots are smart and can do this type of calculation. Why don't you use captcha instead.

Comment: @user689 Image captcha is not much better that text questions. Although I agree that arithmetic questions are pretty easy to parse and answer programmatically. There are better ones, though, like those testing common knowledge or selecting certain letters from a sentence.

Comment: what do you mean doesnt work? what error do you get ?

Comment: Did it work before you uploaded it? (Did you test it?) Did it submit or not? Can you explain what part doesn't work and maybe how you tried to debug it.

Comment: Try this `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); $name = $_POST['name']; ....rest of your PHP code`

Comment: `if ($_POST['submit'] && $human == '4') {…} else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {…}` can be replaced with `if ($_POST['submit']) { if ($human == '4') {…} else {…}}`.

Comment: this appears at the top of my form on the live site                   Your message has been sent!</p>';
    } else {
        echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>';
    }
} else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
    echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
}
?>

Comment: and also it doesn't send the message to my email

Comment: Did you setup your smtp settings?

Comment: Does your web server support PHP?  It looks like it's just serving up the file without running the server-side code (i.e. the PHP isn't run, just sent to the browser directly).  If you view source in your web browser, do you see the PHP code?

Comment: oh that must be it ernie thanks it may not support php then cause i do see the php code when i inspect element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your web server does not support PHP.  PHP runs on the web server (aka server side), and the client side (that is the web browser) should only get valid HTML.

It looks like your webserver is not interpreting the PHP.  A quick check for this would be to view the source in your browser - if you see PHP code there, then the webserver did not run the PHP.

There are many possible reasons for PHP not being interpreted - the php extension not being handled, PHP not being installed, other web server configurations, etc.

Comment: Thanks again ernie i'm new to this so i had no idea. This is for a school project so their server doesn't support php i believe.